# Cart Price Rules - disable general discount after using code

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have a problem, I want to set up discount with a code which offers 50% on a specific product.
But I also have a general discount which offers 20% after buying N products.
I want to disable the general discounts after using the discount with the code.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a cart price rule, there're 2 options available: *Priority* and *Discard Subsequent Rules* (in the Actions tab). If I understand your question correctly, you just need to set the following values:

1. For the discount with the code (50%): Priority = 1 and Discard Subsequent Rules = Yes
2. For the general discount (20%): Priority = 2

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working :( to clarify: The discount with the code offers 50% on specific product (SKU) to up 10x. The general discount offer 50% discount for all products if quantity in cart >10, i applied your solution but didn't work :(